# Check if dictionary keys exists in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am a mid-level beginner in Python and I would like to know if I'm on the right track in this code. In school I have been assigned a file compression task in which we have to make our own algorithm to compress a text file. For the end part of this code I need to iterate over the list and check if any dict keys exist inside it, and if True, convert the list item to the value of the dict. Could anyone tell me if I'm on the right track?

```
commonwords =  {'the' : '@', 'of' : '$', 'to' : '%','and' : '^', 'you' : 
'&', 'because' : '#', 'in' : '*', 'it' : '(', 'is' : ')', 'they' : '=',
            'are' : '+', 'this' : '!','but' : ',', 'have' : '.', 'by' : '/'}

def compress(file):
    file_obj = open(file,"r")
    file_contents = file_obj.read().split()
    for word in file_contents:
        if commonwords.keys() in file_contents:
            file_contents[i] == commonwords[i]
    return file_contents
```

Comment: You are not using your iterator variable, `word`. Is that on purpose? Is `file_conents` in the `if` meant to be `word`?

Comment: You're opening your file using `open()` and made the error of not closing your file director. Python has got a method to handle files correctly. Check out how to use `with` keyword, here it would give you : `with open(file, 'r') as file_obj:`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right. You seem to iterate through words in file but never checking if word is a dictionary key. `i` in your code is not initialized initially and will result in a not defined error and also mind that for assigning values, an assignment operator `=` is used and not an equality operator.

I suggest this code and this should solve your problem:

```
commonwords =  {'the' : '@', 'of' : '$', 'to' : '%','and' : '^', 'you' :  '&', 'because' : '#', 'in' : '*', 'it' : '(', 'is' : ')', 'they' : '=', 'are' : '+', 'this' : '!','but' : ',', 'have' : '.', 'by' : '/'}

def compress(file):
    file_obj = open(file,"r")
    file_contents = file_obj.read().split()
    for x, word in enumerate(file_contents):
        if word in commonwords:
            file_contents[x] = commonwords[word]
    file_obj.close()
    return file_contents
```

*Note* the use of `enumerate` here. It helps you keep track of indices while you iterate through elements of list.

Comment: Why making a simple highly optimized O(1) lookup an inefficient O(N) sequential one ? Delete the `keys = commonwords.keys()` line and just use `if word in commonwords`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks. That was coded in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you want to check if any of the words in file_contents is a key in commonwords?

You can just do

```
for word in file_contents:
    if word in commonwords:
        word.replace(word, commonwords[word])
```

Python understands that you mean the keys if you type "in file_contents".

Answer (score 0):

Close but no cigar... What you want is to check if any of the file's `word`s are in `commonwords`, not if the list of `commonword.keys()` is included (verbatim) in `file_contents`:

```
def compress(file):
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        words = f.read().split()

    for i, word in enumerate(words):
       if word in commonwords: 
            words[i] = commonwords[word]

    return words
```